# Solve $A_{yy} + \frac{2}{y}A_y=0$ for $A(x,y)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Here is my work at solving
\begin{align}
A_{yy} + \frac{2}{y}A_y &=0 \\
\end{align}

I let $p=A_y$ so that $\frac{dp}{dy}=A_{yy}$

now I solve as follows:

\begin{align}
\frac{dp}{dy} &= \frac{-2}{y}p \\
\frac{1}{p}dp &= \frac{-2}{y}dy \\
\ln p &= -2\ln y + \ln C\\
\ln p &= \ln \left(\frac{C}{y^2}\right)\\
p &= \frac{C}{y^2}\\
\end{align}

So this gives me
\begin{align}
A_y &= \frac{C}{y^2}\\
A & = -\frac{C}{y} + b(x)
\end{align}

I checked if this would satisfy the given equation:
\begin{align}
A_{yy} + \frac{2}{y}A_y & = \frac{-2C}{y^3}+ \frac{2}{y} \left( \frac{C}{y^2} \right)\\
&=0
\end{align}

This satisfies the equation. I want to be sure I have the correct answer.

Comment: You should not use $\mathrm{D}_y p$, you should use $\partial_y p$. Your $C$ should be $c(x)$.

Comment: Your solution seems correct.

Comment: Just an FYI. You could also write your DE a $y^2A_{yy} +2yA_y=0$ which is Cauchy Euler in $y$. The substitution $A=y^\lambda$ gives $$\lambda(\lambda-1)y^{\lambda}+2\lambda y^{\lambda}=0 \iff \lambda =0,-1$$ So you general solution becomes $A(x,y)=c_1(x)+\frac{c_2(x)}{y}$ where $c_1,c_2$ are functions of $x$.